# How to get the latest ID from Firebase console from Untiy

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Unity project with Firebase for google Authentication. I am storing user information in a realtime database. They are stored as:

```
UnityProject
    1->
       Name: "Something"
       Email: "Something"
    2->
       Name: "some other thing"
       Email: "Something else"
```

Now, these 1,2 are to be given by me (to be used as a primary key). I would start by giving the first user ID 1 and the second used ID 2 and so on.

But I need to get back from the firebase the last ID which was stored. For example,

```
idToInsert = GetLastUsedID() + 1;
```

I have used this code but it doesn't work. The screen just freezes until I force close Unity.

```
 public int GetLastUsedID()
    {
        int currentID = 1;
        bool continueSearch = true;

        while (continueSearch)
        {
            FirebaseREST.DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseREST.FirebaseDatabase.Instance.GetReference(""+currentID);
            string value = "";
            currentID++;
            reference.GetValueAsync(10, (res) =>
            {
                if (res.success)
                {
                    value = res.data.GetRawJsonValue();
                    Debug.Log("Success fetched data : " + value);
                    if(value == "")
                    {
                        continueSearch = false;
                        Debug.Log(currentID);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("Fetch data failed : " + res.message);
                    continueSearch = false;
                }
            });

        }
        return currentID;
}
```

Basically I am just trying to iterate from 1 till whenever I get the empty string. The empty string means no data exists under that ID.

Comment: Take a good look at your function, especially at the while-loop and .GetValueAsync, as I don't know if that is what you want to achieve. GetValueAsync as name points out do it's job asynchronously, the second it's called the body of your while-loop start working again. I think that is not your intention, am I right?

Comment: I just want to get the last number in the database. In the function im getting the value for id1. If empty string is returned, then i stop the whole loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `FirebaseREST` (I would recommend using the [official Firebase plugin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup) if you're able, it does much more than just call REST endpoints), but I think I can see your issue.

`GetValueAsync` likely runs asynchronously in the background. So the logic inside the block (the `(res)=>` part) is firing off many times (basically infinitely with that while loop). Then, depending on how this is implemented, either `continueSearch` never goes to `false` because it isn't marked [volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile) or the callback logic never gets a chance to run (say if `FirebaseREST` tries to dispatch to the main thread, which is locked in an infinite while loop).

If `GetValueAsync` returns a Task, you can use some of the tips I cover in [this article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html). My recommendation would be to try to use async/await, so your logic would look more like:

```
async public int GetLastUsedID()
{
    volatile int currentID = 1;
    volatile bool continueSearch = true;

    while (continueSearch)
    {
        FirebaseREST.DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseREST.FirebaseDatabase.Instance.GetReference(""+currentID);
        string value = "";
        currentID++;
        await reference.GetValueAsync(10, (res) =>
        {
            if (res.success)
            {
                value = res.data.GetRawJsonValue();
                Debug.Log("Success fetched data : " + value);
                if(value == "")
                {
                    continueSearch = false;
                    Debug.Log(currentID);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Fetch data failed : " + res.message);
                continueSearch = false;
            }
        });
    }
    return currentID;
}
```

This is probably not the case, in which case you'll probably want to turn this into a recursive call. You'd want some function like:

```
public void GetLastUsedID(currentId)
{
        FirebaseREST.DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseREST.FirebaseDatabase.Instance.GetReference(""+currentID);
        reference.GetValueAsync(10, (res) =>
        {
            if (res.success)
            {
                value = res.data.GetRawJsonValue();
                Debug.Log("Success fetched data : " + value);
                if(value == "")
                {
                    continueSearch = false;
                    Debug.Log(currentID);
                }
                else
                {
                    // recurse
                    GetLastID(currentId+1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Fetch data failed : " + res.message);
                continueSearch = false;
            }
        });
}
```

You will have to figure out how to pass in your own callback to bubble a success or failure like this (exercise to the reader).

Finally, I would be a little cautious with what you're doing entirely. If you're authenticating users, I'd recommend using [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/start) which ties directly into Realtime Database. At most you'd only store user id's in there, and use [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) to ensure that only that user can write into it (for instance). By using Firebase Authentication to manage user data and tying that to RTDB rules, you avoid the same mistakes [this author made](https://medium.com/@dramonddaniel/i-bet-you-a-coffee-that-i-can-hack-your-firebase-database-d8f5e045a46b).

Comment: Great answer. So adding new users requires a primary key right. Thats why i was simply relying on an ID variable. Is there a better and/or correct way to do that?

Comment: There isn't quite the concept of a primary key in RTDB that you might expect from a SQL database. You would need a globally unique key of some kind to identify your entry, which you can just use the userid from Firebase Authentication for (you wouldn't want to use a session id or anything else that really should be private though).

If you need to generate a unique key and order doesn't matter, you can always use Guid.NewGuid() and cache that in your PlayerPrefs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: None of this has to be at the root of your database either. You could nest this all under a node called "users" for example and not incur a performance hit.

Comment: Oh okay So my RTDB should look like 
Unity Project ->
    Users -> 1,2,3...

Comment: I will mark this as the correct answer although I haven't tried out the solution. I was having some problem sing the official firebase so i went for FirebaseREST. I will do what you have said with the official firebase :) Thanks

Comment: It _can_ look like that. I'd recommend doing that just so you can put more stuff into your RTDB.

For the non-REST version, if you're shipping on iOS or Android it should generally work really well and I'd love to hear if you get stuck. Desktop is super duper beta though, and it doesn't support other targets (such as the consoles).

Comment: I always get stuck at the gradle part of it... After creating and downloading the google services file and placing it in unity project, the official firebase page tells to modify the gradle file so that the app can try to communicate with the firebase. Unity projects dont have the app.gradle and build.gradle. So i went for third party wrappers.

Comment: It's a little confusing, the Unity process is a little different than Android proper. The good news is that you don't have to do anything to the gradle (or even use one). If you want to give it another chance (perhaps in a test project), I'd recommend looking here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup

That's me in the video, so it's actually super useful to know if you get stuck on anything!

Comment: Whoa I didn't know I was talking to a youtube celebrity :o I have seen you in a few videos already xD. I will definitely have a go at it again today.